# How to access videos in iphone. Where does it store the downloaded videos?

Tags: iphone, video

How do I access videos on an iPhone? Where does it store downloaded videos?

Is there any sample code available to access the videos on an iPhone?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a blog post that covers the basics of using a UIImagePickerController to acquire a video.

http://sol3.typepad.com/tagalong_developer_journa/2009/07/recorded-video-from-iphone-3gs-.html

You should elaborate on what you are trying to do once you've read that.

Comment: If we are manually adding any videos to iphone using iTunes then where does it store that video?

Answer (score 4):

There is no (documented) way to programmatically access the video/photo library without user interaction. Your only choice is to instantiate and display a `UIImagePickerController` and let the user select a video.

Comment: Can we do filtering in the UIImagePickercontroller to only show videos.