# Access the videos in Videos app of an iOS device in my app

Tags: video, ios5

I am developing an application to choose and and play videos in iPad. I want to choose the videos saved in the default Videos app present in the device. How can I access those videos in my application?

Comment: What do you mean by "default videos app present in the device", they are in a folder within your app, or in the bundle ?

Comment: Videos app is the built in app in the device like photos, contacts, phonebooth etc. i want access the videos in that default videos app and not from camera roll. how can i do that?

Comment: For the you've to accesss `UIImagePickerController` try referring this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631778/how-to-access-videos-in-iphone-where-does-it-store-the-downloaded-videos

Comment: Do you want to access videos in photo library ?

Comment: UIImagePickerController opens the Camera roll path right? i dont want that to happen. I just want to open the videos in the default videos app of the device. videos app is available in iOS4.3 & later.

Comment: Not from the photo library. i want to access videos in the videos app.

Comment: I have uploaded the screeenshot of the video app i am talking about. Marked the red circle to the app. Hope you got it.

Comment: ps. Just now I find one app in my iPad can access the video.app list. And my iPad is with ios 5.1.1. Maybe it is possible now!

Comment: which app is Accessing the inbuilt videos app in your iPad? name the app... And is your iPad Jailbreaked to access that?

Comment: Did you ever find out if this is possible? And if so, how is it possible? I have the same problem! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an MPMediaQuery for videos which will give you a list of videos and urls for the video assets that you can use in the AVFoundation framework.  For an example, see the accepted answer here:

[MPMediaPickerController with video media types not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474287/mpmediapickercontroller-with-video-media-types-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

The current SDK does not allow you to play videos from the iPod library:

http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH103-SW9

> Note: iPod library access applies only to audio-based media items. You cannot play video podcasts, movies, or television shows from the iPod library.

Comment: I have uploaded the screeenshot of the video app i am talking about. Marked the red circle to the app. Hope you got it

Answer (score 0):

search `UIImagePickerController` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

If you want to access the inbuilt videos app in the device itself, I think it is impossible without break jail your ipad.

ps. Just now I find one app in my iPad can access the video.app list. And my iPad is with ios 5.1.1. Maybe it is possible now!

Comment: I don't want to access the camera roll using uiimagepickercontroller. but i want to access the inbuilt videos app in the device itself. How can i do that?

Comment: It seems impossible without break jail

Comment: What is the method if i jailbreak the device? infact i want to access that through my application, so why should i jailbreak the device?

Comment: I don't know. You can only access data in the sandbox of your app.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS development, you can't always do exactly anything you want to do in the phone. Accessing other apps is one of these things. In this case you want to access the data of a built in iOS-app. This app is just like any other app, except it is made by Apple, and it doesn't mean that you can access it's data.

Apps have their own data and apps cannot access data from other applications. (unless it's made available by the app somehow, for example via a web server)

If you are making your app with the intention to release it for official use, what you´re asking can not be done. You will have to make the best of your situation, make your app better than the built-in app so that the users use your app instead of the built in one.