# How can I play an existing video in Xcode with iOS5?

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access the videos in Videos app of an iOS device in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680427/access-the-videos-in-videos-app-of-an-ios-device-in-my-app)

I want to present something like UIImagePickerController so the user can select a video from the **"Movies" app** or from the **Camera Roll**. Then I want to play with the MPMoviePlayer.

I found a lot of explanations about how to open a video from the Camera Roll (Photo Library, anyway), but I found nothing about **playing a video from the Movies app**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680427/access-the-videos-in-videos-app-of-an-ios-device-in-my-app

Exactly your problem