# iOS Any way to retrieve all videos?

Tags: ios, video, movie

I have to get list of videos from device. I know how to get videos from camera roll with help of UIImagePickerController. But, using UIImagePickerController, I can't get videos that are shown in the "Videos" application (standard iOS application).

What should I use? Is any standard(or GitHub) controller for my purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, finally with help of **Lyndsey Scott** I've answered my own question:

1. There no standard control to get video from media library (UIImagePickerController get videos only from camera roll or albums).
2. So, I use next code to get and enum Videos:

   ```
   MPMediaQuery *videoQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

   NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
   NSArray *mediaItems = [videoQuery items];

   // Maybe do something with title and URL
   for (MPMediaItem *mediaItem in mediaItems) {
       NSURL *URL = (NSURL*)[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
       if (URL) {
           NSString *title = (NSString*)[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
       }
   }
   ```

and then I've created my own ViewController with fetched list of movies.

P.S. If I've missed something or have posted wrong answer - please correct me

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate through an `ALAssetsLibrary` object to get all of the videos, ex:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* videoAssets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) { 
     if (group) {
         [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];    
         [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) { 
              if (asset) {
                  [videoAssets addObject:asset];
              }
         }];
     }
}
```

And then if you want a video url for example, you can access it from the asset using `[[asset defaultRepresentation] url]`.

**Update:** And your `UIImagePickerController` will show only photos and albums containing photos by default, but your "Videos" album should come up if you also specify that you'd like your `UIImagePickerController` to display video, ex:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeImage, nil];

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:true completion:nil];
```

where `kUTTypeMovie` and `kuTTypeImage` are part of the MobileCoreServices framework.

Comment: Lyndsey Scott, thanks. But is there any standard controller for choosing video from list?

Comment: Lyndsey Scott, I've checked out your code and investigate that I can not get videos from "Media Library", but only from assest Library. My purpose is to load videos like the Videos standard application (not only from albums and camera roll)

Comment: @slavik Are you referring to the first bit of code I posted or the second?

Comment: Both (first and second) samples do not return all videos from device (only from "camera roll").

Comment: @slavik Oh, misunderstood your question. I don't think what you're trying to do is possible, but here's another post on the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10680427/2274694